# Post html form to Telegram user

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, telegram

I need to send HTML form data (inputs valsues, select options etc.) to telegram user.

I found that first I need a Telegram bot, I made it with @botFather:

```
/newbot
```

But I don't know, what to do now. I need to send this form via JS or jQuery, because form data calculate and insert in form from other website block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand how to do it. Sample is:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot[token]/sendMessage?   disable_web_page_preview=true&chat_id=[chat_id]&text=Hello';  
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$page = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Html and a php file.

In the Html file add the following code:

```
 <form action="form.php">

        Name:<br>
       
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
       
        <br>
        Mobile number:
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" minlength="3" maxlength="15"  size="15">
        <br>
        
        Message:<br>
       
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" rows="6" cols="33"></textarea>
       
        <br><br>
       
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
       
       </form>
```

And in php file paste this

```
<?php
define ('url',"*token tlg bot*");

$name = $_GET['name'];

$message = $_GET['message'];

$phone = $_GET['phone'];

$chat_id = '{your chat id}';

$message = urlencode("Name:".$name."\nPhone: ".$phone."\nMessage: ".$message);

file_get_contents(url."sendmessage?text=".$message."&chat_id=".$chat_id."&parse_mode=HTML");

?>
```

1. Create your telegram bot using @BotFather
2. Press /start
3. After this u'll get your's bot token
4. Create chat (u must do it, because u'll get sms)
5. Open your browser and input https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getUpdates , where XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX - token, what u've got from @BotFather
6. Input this token and chat id in php below:

DONE!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$username = $_POST["username"];

header("Location:https://api.telegram.org/bot[bot_tocken]/sendMessage?chat_id=[your_chat_id]&text=+'$username'+");
?>
```